# How to change the color of a horizontal line created with a view?

Tags: android, view, colors, line

I have a horizontal line created with a view like this:

```
<View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/led_connection"
            android:layout_height="5dip"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp" />
```

I want to know how can I change the color programatically. Because I am trying to use setBackground and setBackgroundDrawable but SDK sais me that it cannot applied to a View.

I'm getting the view with this:

```
View led_connection = (View)v.findViewById(R.id.led_connection);
```

Comment: Can you show some code that you tried to use to set the background?
My guess is that you are trying to pass in a resource ID without properly getting the resource first (e.g. through `getResources().getColor(R.color.your_color)`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
led_connection.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00FF00);
```

See [docs for details](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundColor%28int%29)

Answer (score 1):

If you have html colors, can try this to solve your problem.

```
led_connection.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#679456"));
led_connection.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("html_code_colors"));
```

Answer (score 0):

As Marcin Orlowski sais, the solution is use setBackgroundColor with an hex color with the 2 first digits that are alpha level.

I'm using for GREEN:

```
led_connection.setBackgroundColor(0xFF008000);  // GREEN
```

and for RED:

```
led_connection.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFF0000);  // RED
```

Thank you